# Spark RDD affinity/Manual collocation of partitions with data

Tags: apache-spark

If I know that a given partition of a dataset is on a given server (for instance, let's say I know a shard or region of a database is on that server via some kind of database specific metadata API) can I exploit that when I create an RDD via SparkContext.parallelize? Basically I'd like to create an RDD from a list of servers, and for each server a function to create a co-located partition of the RDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by subclassing RDD and overriding the method below.

```
/**
 * Optionally overridden by subclasses to specify placement preferences.
 */
protected def getPreferredLocations(split: Partition): Seq[String] = Nil
```

There is an example of this from Hortonworks here: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/hbase/HBaseTableScan.scala

I ended up writing this up [as a blog post](http://richardstartin.uk/co-locating-spark-partitions-with-hbase-regions/)